# Why saving of 32-bit sample rate, PCM float byte[] to wav file creates distortion/crackling?

Tags: java, audio, wav, pcm, sample-rate

I have the following two function that loads any given WAV file into a byte array and gets the format (i.e. `AudioFormat`) of a given WAV file respectively:

```
private byte[] getAudioData(String wavPath) throws IOException, UnsupportedAudioFileException {
    byte[] data = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); // The stream that collects all the audio byte data
    File audioFile = new File(wavPath);
    AudioInputStream audioIS = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(audioFile);

    /*
     * Reads all the bytes from the audio files.
     * It can only read a certain length of bytes at a time, hence the intermediate buffer.
     */
    byte[] intermediateBuffer = new byte[4096];
    int numberOfBytesRead;
    while((numberOfBytesRead = audioIS.read(intermediateBuffer, 0, intermediateBuffer.length)) != -1){
        byteArrayOS.write(intermediateBuffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead);
    }

    audioIS.close();
    byteArrayOS.close();
    data = byteArrayOS.toByteArray();   // Gets total number of bytes in the audio file.
    return data;
}

private AudioFormat getAudioFormat(String wavPath) throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException {
    File audioFile = new File(wavPath);
    AudioInputStream audioIS = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(audioFile);

    AudioFormat audioFormat = audioIS.getFormat();
    audioIS.close();

    return audioFormat;
}
```

Now, I have the following saving function that **1.)** loads the format of the WAV file, **2.)** loads the data from the WAV file, and finally **3.)** saves everything to a new file.

```
public void saveAudio(String wavPath, File destination) throws IOException, UnsupportedAudioFileException {
    AudioFormat format = getAudioFormat(wavPath);
    byte[] audioData = getAudioData(wavPath);

    ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayIS = new ByteArrayInputStream(audioData);
    AudioInputStream audioIS = new AudioInputStream(byteArrayIS, format, audioData.length);

    AudioSystem.write(audioIS, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, destination);
}
```

If the original data is 16-bit sample rate, PCM-signed audio, everything works just fine. However, if the audio is 32-bit sample rate, PCM-float audio, the resulting saved audio file produces a lot of crackling noise with very distorted audio.

Why does this happen? Do any of the functions I reply on only allow 16-bit sample rate audio?

Comment: this post iv linked below complains of no 32 bit support - but you aren't getting the unsupported exception. maybe it's converting it 16 bit (or something else) and then you re-save it marked as 32 bit? try printing the length of the byte array and see if it's what you expect for 32 bit audio. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261812/java-audiosystem-reading-32-bit-wav-files

Comment: This might help as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17370661/what-exactly-does-audioinputstream-read-method-return